# The react-hook-form library and React Ref

Tags: reactjs

Having such a simple `react-hook-form` example form:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function ReactForm() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  let textInput = null;

  function handleClick() {
    textInput.focus();
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

      <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input 
        id="firstName"
        ref={(input) => { 
          console.log("firstName ref...")
          textInput = input
          }
        }
        {...register('firstName')} />
      <br/>

      <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <input id="lastName" { ...register('lastName', { required: true })} /><br/>

      <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
      <input id="age" {...register('age', { pattern: /\d+/ })} />     

      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      /><br/>
      
      <input type="submit" />

      {errors.firstName && <p>First name is required!</p>}
      {errors.lastName && <p>Last name is required!</p>}      
      {errors.age && <p>Please enter number for age!</p>}

    </form>
  );
}
```

I'm getting :

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')

error. The reason for this is that the `ref` seems not to be called at all (NOT giving the the `firstName ref...` in the console). Why doesn't the `ref` NOT being called & working!?

P.S.

I'he rewritten the above WITHOUT using the `react-hook-form` and the `ref` do work as expected so the problem lies somewhere in the `react-hook-form` library!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ref` prop is being overridden by react-hook-form's register. The [result of register includes it's own `ref` property](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/1150dc7752410e490ae32154592e67ca03d1cd23/src/types/form.ts#L149) that you're spreading onto the `input`. The docs indicate this is used for focusing the field on validation errors.

Your exception occurs in your click handler because your ref callback was never executed (and `textInput` is still null).

Try swapping the order so you override the `ref` provided by `register('firstName')` like so:

```
<input 
  id="firstName"
  {...register('firstName')} // spread result of register including ref prop
  ref={(input) => { // override ref prop
    console.log("firstName ref...")
    textInput = input
  }}
/>
```